# .clone doesn't not appear to be incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, auto-increment, mask

this script is suppose to clone a new row of a HTML table. It does not seem to be incrementing the name, id, attributes. What am I doing wrong? The only other thing that is not working is get the value from the previous input id of #endtime_* and putting it in the cloned input id of #starttime_* although I think that is because it does seem to be incrementing as it clones a row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MaskTime(){
    var index = $("#TimeCard tbody>tr").length-1;

$('#endtime_'+index).mask("99:99 aa");
$('#starttime_'+index).mask("99:99 aa");    
}
function update_rows(){
    $("#TimeCard tbody>tr:odd").css("background-color", "#FFF");
    $("#TimeCard tbody>tr:even").css("background-color", "#999");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addrow").click(function() {
        var row = $('#TimeCard tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#TimeCard tbody>tr:last');
        var index = $("#TimeCard tbody>tr").length-1;
        var endvalue = $('#endtime_'+index-1).val();
        $("td:eq(0) select").attr("name", 'type_'+index).attr("id", 'type_'+index).addClass("validate[required]").val('')
        $("td:eq(1)").html("&nbsp;")
        $("td:eq(2) select").attr("name", 'propid_'+index).attr("id", 'propid_'+index).addClass("validate[required]").val('')
        $("td:eq(3)").html("&nbsp;")
        $("td:eq(4) input").attr("name", 'starttime_'+index).attr("id", 'starttime_'+index).addClass("validate[required,custom[timeclock]]").val(endvalue)
        $("td:eq(5) input").attr("name", 'endtime_'+index).attr("id", 'endtime_'+index).addClass("validate[required,custom[timeclock]]").val('')
        $("td:eq(6)").html("&nbsp;")

        update_rows();
        MaskTime();

      return false;
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question:

> It does not seem to be incrementing the name, id, attributes.

Your script isn't giving the proper context for where the tds are for which you want to modify the attribues, etc.

Here's a modification that corrects that, adding a new variable "newrow" (to reduce DOM calls) and modifying the lines of code related to td:eq(#)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addrow").click(function() {
        var row = $('#TimeCard tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#TimeCard tbody>tr:last');
        var index = $("#TimeCard tbody>tr").length-1;
        var endvalue = $('#endtime_'+index-1).val();
        var newrow = $("#TimeCard tbody>tr:last");
        newrow.children("td:eq(0)").children("select").attr("name", 'type_'+index).attr("id", 'type_'+index).addClass("validate[required]").val('')
        newrow.children("td:eq(1)").html("&nbsp;")
        newrow.children("td:eq(2)").children("select").attr("name", 'propid_'+index).attr("id", 'propid_'+index).addClass("validate[required]").val('')
        newrow.children("td:eq(3)").html("&nbsp;")
        newrow.children("td:eq(4)").children("input").attr("name", 'starttime_'+index).attr("id", 'starttime_'+index).addClass("validate[required,custom[timeclock]]").val(endvalue)
        newrow.children("td:eq(5)").children("input").attr("name", 'endtime_'+index).attr("id", 'endtime_'+index).addClass("validate[required,custom[timeclock]]").val('')
        newrow.children("td:eq(6)").html("&nbsp;")

        update_rows();
        MaskTime();

      return false;
    });
});
```

Also, I'd made a jsfiddle with the above: http://jsfiddle.net/m78UN/2/

I'm not following what you're wanting when you describe your second problem:

> The only other thing that is not working is get the value from the previous input id of #endtime_* and putting it in the cloned input id of #starttime_*

...so I've not attempted to address that.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I created a fiddle as well with the actual table. http://jsfiddle.net/MrWizard/qxgcz/

Comment: It is still not doing what it needs. After the third row is added the mask is then applied to all the starttime inputs or all the endtime inputs at once when you click into just one of them. The validate class is from formValidator and it to applies to all the fields at once even if some have good entries. unfortunatly with the script loaded it would be hard to recreate in jsfiddle. The other problem that I am trying to solve is taking the user inputted value of say #endtime_1 and when they click the add row button it automatically puts it into the input value of #starttime_2

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do everything you're doing in a way simpler way. I don't have your original HTML, but check this out as a possible alternative. It mainly does 3 things:

1. Removed IDs used for finding things
2. Caches selectors
3. Adds classes to time inputs to make them easier to reference
4. Removed `MaskTime()` function

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $timecard = $("#TimeCard");
  var $tbody = $timecard.find("tbody");
  var $rows = $tbody.children("tr");
  $("#addrow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // clearer than return false
    var $lastRow = $tbody.find("tr:last-of-type");
    var lastEnd = $lastRow.find(".endTime").val();
    var $newRow = $lastRow.clone(true).appendTo($tbody);
    var $cols = $newRow.find("td");
    var index = $rows.length - 1;
    $cols.eq(0).find("select").attr("name", 'type_' + index).addClass("validate[required]").val('');
    $cols.eq(1).empty();
    $cols.eq(2).find("select").attr("name", 'propid_' + index).addClass("validate[required]").val('');
    $cols.eq(3).empty();
    $cols.eq(4).find("input").attr("name", 'starttime_' + index).addClass("time startTime validate[required,custom[timeclock]]").val(lastEnd);
    $cols.eq(5).find("input").attr("name", 'endtime_' + index).addClass("time endTime validate[required,custom[timeclock]]").val('');
    $cols.eq(6).empty();
    update_rows(); // no idea what this is
    $newRow.find(".time").mask("99:99 aa"); // MaskTime() just did this
  });
});
```

Comment: either way does not work. It appears that it is making each one 1 instead of adding 1 to it... ie propid_1 then by theory the next call of ('propid_'+index) should make it propid_2

Comment: check the updated version. it's simpler and doesn't rely on indexes nearly as much as before. hope it provides some explanation as to what you were doing wrong.!

Comment: I setup a jsfiddle... now you can see what some of my issues are. http://jsfiddle.net/MrWizard/qxgcz/4/